# Difference between partial sort, total sort and secondary sort in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Please let me know the Difference between partial sort, total sort and secondary sort in hadoop

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Sort**:-

The reducer output will be lot of files each of which is sorted within itself based on the key.

**Total Sort**:

The reducer output will be a single file having all the output sorted based on the key.

**Secondary Sort**:

In this case, we will be able to control the ordering of the values along with the keys.That is sorting can be done on two or more field values.

Comment: Are these two partial sorting and total sort concepts applicable for MAP tasks only? 
Is Secondary sort related to total sorting?

Comment: Partial sort and total sort are not only for map tasks...... Secondary sort is different from total sort

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Sort:**

N number of Mappers will simply generate N number of files. N number of reducers will sort these files individually.

**Total Sort**

All key value pairs from a particular Key will reach a particular reducer. This will happen through Partitioners at Mapper level. Combiners at Mapper level will act as Semi reducers and send values of a particular key to Reducer.

The reducer output will be a single file having all the output sorted based on the key.

**Secondary Sort**

Used to define how map output keys are sorted. It works at Mapper level. In this case, we will be able to control the ordering of the values along with the keys.That is sorting can be done on two or more field values.

Have a look at [article1](http://datatwist.blogspot.in/2015/05/sorting-in-mapreduce.html) and [article2](http://blog.zaloni.com/secondary-sorting-in-hadoop) and [article3](https://chasebradford.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/reusable-total-order-sorting-in-hadoop/)