# Number of Reducers and output order

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I use the function `job.setNumReduceTasks(1);`, I get the output sorted by key. However, the output is not sorted by key when I remove this function.

So, should we expect to get sorted output from the reducer when we have more than one reducer task?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Can you give some data to show that the reducer output is not sorted?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298159/difference-between-partial-sort-total-sort-and-secondary-sort-in-hadoop/33301253#33301253 and  http://blog.zaloni.com/secondary-sorting-in-hadoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is sorted on the key within a single Reducer. However the default Partitioner is the result of a hash function, and so whilst each file will be sorted if using multiple Reducers, one file will not be a sorted continuation of the last. For example:

We have a word count job with three Reducers. The Mapper outputs:

```
(A,1)
(zebra,1)
(bat,1)
(zebra,1)
(frog,1)
(A,1)
```

The Partitioner looks like the following

```
public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
```

and so it could allocate the keys in the following way:

```
REDUCER 1    REDUCER 2    REDUCER 3
(A,1)        (frog,1)     (bat,1)
(A,1)       
(zebra,1)
```

Notice that `Reducer 1` doesn't contain A-F, `Reducer 2` doesn't contain G-M and `Reducer 3` doesn't contain N-Z, i.e. it's not splitting alphabetically. And that's why the overall output won't be sorted, but data will be sorted within each Reducer's output.

This makes sense as otherwise we could end up with a big skew. Say for example you're running a MapReduce job on some customer services data where the ID always starts with `C` - you wouldn't want everything to go to the same Reducer.